# How to fix this UV distortion on a face?

Tags: uv

I am trying to UV map a model of some robot tracks, so that a texture with horizontal lines wraps evenly around it. However I am running into an issue whereby everything looks okay, except for the outer faces, where instead of the line traveling straight across to the other side, there is some kind distortion running diagonally across the face. I know this is related to the face being made up of 2 triangles but how do I go about fixing this?

Here is a screen shot of the issue:
[image]

Comment: The side faces are not rectangular in shape, they are actually trapezoidal in shape, so the UV map as to reflect that and mimic its shape so no distortions are introduced

Comment: This looks like something I was checking out a few days ago. Check to see if subdivisions help. The question: https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/81380/why-does-an-even-subdivide-change-the-displayed-texture